# Grab all VMs in Hyper-V cluster Windows 2012 R2 and their disks sizes

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I'm trying to get html report with provisined disks size for all VMs in cluster. I'm trying to list all VMs inside cluster with:

```
$VMs = get-ClusterGroup | ? {$_.GroupType -eq "VirtualMachine" } | Get-VM
```

And this works like a charm. However when I'm trying make a loop:

```
foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
 Get-VM -VMName $VM.Name | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD
}
```

I'm getting error for each VM that is not located on my current cluster node when I'm running this.
So per each node I'm running following command:

```
Get-VM -VMName * | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | ConvertTo-HTML -Proprerty path,computername,vhdtype,@{label='Size(GB)');expression={$_.filesize/1gb -as [int]}} > report.html
```

And this works like a charm also. But this is require to login to each Hyper-V host in cluster.
How to make it happened to get output in HTML with all VMs in cluster from one node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
$nodes = Get-ClusterNode
foreach($node in $nodes)
{
    $VMs=Get-VM -ComputerName $node.name
    foreach($VM in $VMs)
    {
        $VM.VMName
        Get-VHD -ComputerName $node.Name -VMId $VM.VMId | ft vhdtype,path -AutoSize
    }
}
```

From what I can tell; you need the node name as `-ComputerName` and `-VMId` for each Get-VHD call.
Passing the Get-VM to Get-VHD doesn't provide the node name for some reason.

What you are looking for, the above does not provide the results as a single Object to be formatted (html or otherwise).
There is however an inline `ForEach-Object` that will do the trick.

This is maybe what you are looking for:

```
Get-VM -ComputerName (Get-ClusterNode) | 
ForEach-Object {Get-VHD -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -VMId $_.VMId} | 
ConvertTo-HTML -Property path,computername,vhdtype,@{label='Size(GB)';expression={$_.filesize/1gb -as [int]}} > report.html
```

In a single line:

```
Get-VM -ComputerName (Get-ClusterNode) | ForEach-Object {Get-VHD -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -VMId $_.VMId} | ConvertTo-HTML -Property path,computername,vhdtype,@{label='Size(GB)';expression={$_.filesize/1gb -as [int]}} > report.html
```

Hope this meets your needs. Enjoy!